# angular unknown provider error when published site

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular-module

I have developed a little app and now i wanted to publish it to azure for the first time.

It's my first time i use angular in any project and i have got something wrong. 
 I get this error:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: sProvider <- s <- MapController

this is my controller:

```
 var app = angular.module("TravelPlanner", []);


var mapController = function ($scope, $http) {
    lots of functions....

 }


   app.controller("MapController", mapController);
```

and here is my layout page:

```
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyASli52h7eL3W1CSNtTrl-S71zDFATqbDg&libraries=places"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
<script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>



@*<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/plugin.min.js"></script>*@
</head>
<body ng-app="TravelPlanner">
   <div class="container body-content" ng-controller="MapController">
             @RenderBody()
    </div>


@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

why do i get this angular error?

** EDIT **
  Here is the bundle where i load my scripts.

```
         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                  "~/Scripts/Angular.js",
                   "~/Scripts/DropZone.js",
                  "~/Content/Scripts/gmaps.js",
                  "~/Content/Scripts/jquery.geocomplete.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js",
                  "~/Content/Scripts/MapController.js",
                  "~/Content/Scripts/sweetalert.min.js"
                 ));
```

mapcontroller.js is where all my angular/js code is. (don't know why i haven't changed the name of the bundle, guess i'm to lazy)

Comment: do you load your custom scripts in the head section or at the end of the body?

Comment: Yes! I made a comment with my bundle. Could they be in the wrong order of some kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to annotate your dependency for mapController

```
var mapController = ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    lots of functions....

 }];
```

Check out this link here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation

Answer (score 0):

You cannot minimize AngularJS app using "standard" ASP.NET bundles. There are two options:

1. Do not minimize AngularJS *app* files, only remove whitespaces and comments from it (there are nuget packages that do exactly that).
2. Use explicit injector annotations, and minimize `.js` files using standard techniques, for your controller you must change:

   app.controller("MapController", mapController);

into:

```
app.controller("MapController", ['$http', mapController]);
```

More about injector can be found [in official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)